# How can I create a simple loop through entries in a category?

Tags: templating, categories, loop

I have a category set up and have added entries to it. How do I loop through these entries, and output just the title of each entry?

Serious noob here but trying to learn, any help would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This example assumes you have your [Category Group](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/categories#category-groups) setup to use custom URLs.  In the template used to display your categories, the `category` variable will be available and represent your [CategoryModel](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/categorymodel) for that page.

The key is to pass the `CategoryModel` (in our example below `category`) to the `relatedTo` parameter of the Entries tag.

```
{{ category.title }}

{% paginate craft.entries
    .section('articles')
    .relatedTo(category)
    .limit(10) 
    as entries 
%}

    {% if entries|length %}

        {# Content #}
        {% for entry in entries %}
            {{ entry.title }}
        {% endfor %}

        {# Pagination #}

    {% else %}

        <p>No items have been added to this Category yet.</p>

    {% endif %}

{% endpaginate %}
```

Comment: Thanks Ben, this has allowed me to loop through all the entries in my channel (only have 1 as I'm using the personal version), I think I am missing something, maybe in the setup of my category group. I'll go back to it and have a root around, many thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Here's another good example for working with categories that may be useful to you. This will loop through all categories (that have entries) and show their entries:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('someSection').limit(null) %}

{% for category in craft.categories.group('someCategoryGroup').relatedTo(entries) %}
    <h2>{{ category }}</h2>

    {% for entry in entries.relatedTo(category) %}
        {{ entry.title }}
    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```